# Error when running after installing jasper plugin

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, jira, jasper-plugin

I am having a problem, when I installed the grails jasper, I got this error:

Error Error running script run-app -verbose: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of  previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo"

This has been already in jira but still unresolved yet. Anyone have an idea how to do this please?

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPJASPER-50

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPEXPORT-18 it seems to be the same case.
You would probably need to exclude xmlbeans from the jasper plugin:

```
plugins {
    compile(":jasper:1.6.1") {
        excludes "xmlbeans "
    }
}
```